# How to constrain scipy optimize in a time series

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize a function where each parameter in my list of parameters is less than 0.1 away from the last. In other words, the parameter for each step in the time series follows the constraint abs(t[i]-t[i-1]) < 0.1. My thought so far is to constrain this using an equality constraint for scipy.optimize.minimize() function, but it doesn't seem to be producing the correct result and this isn't really an equality constraint. Here is my constraint code (I don't include the first element because that is a separate parameter):

```
def con(t):
    t = t[1:]
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, len(t)):
        if (abs(t[i] - t[i-1]) > 0.1):
            total += abs(t[i] - t[i-1])
            break
    return total

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': con}]

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, my_params, args = (x_list), constraints = cons)
```

where my_params are generated randomly from random.uniform(-1,1) and x_list is gathered data. Is there a better/alternate way to describe this constraint. I've been trying to make sense of scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint, but I'm not sure how to implement it or if that would be applicable.

For example, I have tried the following:

```
def nonlincon(t):
    t = t[1:]
    diff_list = []
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        diff_list.append(abs(t[i]-t[i-1]))
    return diff_list

cons = [scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(nonlincon,-np.inf,0.1)]
```

but the resulting parameter vector does not end up satisfying the constraint still.